# Are there any Jewish miracles?

Tags: tanach, agada-stories-legends, miracle

I, from an outside faith is studying Judaism. However, I do have a question - are there any Jewish miracles (exclusively Jewish, those that are particular to the faith)?

For example, in Christianity some believe in Bernadette having seen Virgin Mary. Muslims believe in the splitting of the moon, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Talmud is replete with miracles.  The first 5 pages of the 5th chapter of Tractate Bava Basra (beginning [here](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3405&size=1) and ending [here](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3410&size=1)) are almost entirely dedicated to miraculous stories that happened to Rabba Bar Bar Channa.

Many of the miracles of the Talmud are subject to discussion if they are meant to be taken literally.  However, some are generally accepted to be literal.  For example, Tractate [Taanis 25a](http://kodesh.snunit.k12.il/b/l/l2803_025a.htm) has the account of Rebbi Chanina, whose wife accidentally lit vinegar for the Sabbath candles.  Upon hearing her distress, Rebbi Chanina responded that "he who said that oil will light will let the vinegar light," and thus it happened that it stayed lit. (Taking this as non-literal would absolve the story of all meaning.)

Comment: "Taking this as non-literal would absolve the story of all meaning." ??????

Comment: Yes - if the vinegar didn't actually light, then... nothing really happened.  He was referring to an ideal which wasn't actually true?  Hypothetically could have been?

Comment: I didn't suggest only the end of the story didnt happen. I mean the whole thing didn't happen (his wife never actually goofed), and it's a story which reinforces that God will help you in times of need. I don't know if it's a true story or not, but neither does anyone else, and frankly it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: How do you see from the story that G-d will help you, from a story that didn't actually happen?  If I make stories up can I teach lessons from them?  If there was symbolism, good.  But here it's pretty straight forward what the lesson was.

Comment: Is that a joke? 98% of fantasy tales are stories that show Good wins. Of course you can teach lessons from made up stories.

Comment: ... and therefore?  The fact that fantasy stories show something doesn't give them any value.  It's like being inspired from Hanoch Teller stories- if it didn't happen, I don't see that it could from your made up story.

Comment: Hanoch Teller is not Chazal. If Chazal told a fantasy tale to teach a message, you can bet your bottom dollar I'd be focusing on every word.